# Excel - Button to go to a certain sheets

Tags: excel, hyperlink

[Excel - Button to go to a certain sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075921/excel-button-to-go-to-a-certain-sheet)     I cannot comment so i inserted a link. My question, is this possible non-volatile way? I mean, when i assign hyperlink to a object, after execution, excel asks before exit: "Do you want to save chan...." Is it possible to create non-volatile sheets links?

Comment: Not without VBA, I don't think. Why not just save after you create the hyperlink?

Comment: Hyperlink is volatile. There is no way. Or maybe with VBA and put to the end something like: Workbook.save:=False ?  Or this isn't the best way, 'cause if I do change some cell value and click on hyperlink, excel won't save my work :(