Creating a hyperlink to a sheet with name based on cell
I have a series of about 25 sheets in an excel workbook. The 1st sheet is a summary page with all the sheet names listed in column B.
i.e. B4 has the name of the sheet, A4 will have the hyperlink automatically taking you to the sheet with the same name. And so on for the rest of A and B columns. I keep trying this stacked hyperlink/indirect formula but am met with a SPILL or REF error:
=HYPERLINK(INDIRECT("'"&$B4&"'!A1:B4",TRUE), "Click Here")

I also tried the below and received a NAME error:
=HYPERLINK("#'" & B4 & "'!A4", Click Here

Any thoughts on what else I can try? Originally had a button inserted with a macro but it seemed difficult to create a different one for each row.

I recommend a Macro-button. See if this thread helps you do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075921/excel-button-to-go-to-a-certain-sheet

To do it with a hyper link the link must contain the name of the file.  To make that dynamic we can use CELL()
=HYPERLINK(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1)),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1)&B4&"!A1:B4","Click Here")

One caveat is that the workbook must have been saved at least once.
A slightly shorter version with Office 365:
=HYPERLINK("["&CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(CELL("filename"),{"[","]"}),2)&"]"&B4&"!A1:B4","here")

